# need to put empty row in my ng repeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have a little problem, i need to put a empty row in my ng repeat

i explain ,

I would like to set up an empty array with filled, for example, today I have 8 record (1 to 8 am, 4 to 10am and 3 to 3pm) and per hour I would like to have minimum 4 fields (as I have a record at 8am I must have 3 fields empty more and as I have nothing 9am I must have 4 fields empty ...)

First I wanted to go from the filter side, I wanted to take the time of object conversation and test it with the next conversation object, but the next function does not work

```
$.each(conversations, function (index, conversation)
        {

          ///i want to get my next object to test hours
            console.log($(this).next());




            var conversationDate = moment(conversation.dateenvoi);

            //alert(conversationDate)
            if (conversationDate >= startDate && conversationDate <= endDate)
            {
               result.push(conversation);

            }
        });
```

i created a plunker for more help

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4uPrswSaB4fwBneLAzU?p=preview

thanks for your help

EDIT

I have for example 8 recording

1 to 8 am
4 to 10am 
3 to 3pm

my ng repeat Will make this one

8:00 gabi
10:00 jean
10:00 marc
10:00 salvator
10:00 oneil
3:00 francois
3:00 frank
3:00 susan

but me i want this one in my ng repeat

8:00 gabi
8:00 x
8:00 x
8:00 x
9:00 x
9:00 x
9:00 x
9:00 x
10:00 jean
10:00 marc
10:00 salvator
10:00 oneil
11:00 x
11:00 x
11:00 x
11:00 x
12:00 x
12:00 x
12:00 x
12:00 x
1:00 x
1:00 x
1:00 x
1:00 x
2:00 x
2:00 x
2:00 x
2:00 x
3:00 francois
3:00 frank
3:00 susan
3:00 x

when there are no record i put X

Comment: Please explain your requirement properly.

Comment: Ok Ananya , please check my Edit

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've done it.
See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZT3h4KP5rgZRL7mgs0qa?p=preview)

Notice, that conversations must be ordered by conversation date.

Also in my opinion, it's better to add empty rows before the filtering, somewhere in controller. You can just copy you conversations to another variable and use for adding empty rows and then passing it to ng-repeat. In this case you daterange filter will be just 'daterange' filter and nothing more.

```
app.filter('daterange', function() {
    return function(conversations, startDate, endDate) {
    var result = [];
    var perHourCount = 4; //it's better to obtain this value using grouping by hour and getting max value
    var firstDate, lastDate;

// date filters
    endDate = moment(startDate).add(1, 'days').subtract(7300, 'second');

    var startDate = (startDate && !isNaN(Date.parse(startDate))) ? Date.parse(startDate) : moment('2015-01-01');
    var endDate = (endDate && !isNaN(Date.parse(endDate))) ? Date.parse(endDate) : moment('2050-12-31');

// if the conversations are loaded
    if (conversations && conversations.length > 0) {
        var filteredByDateRange = conversations.filter(function(x) {
        var conversationDate = moment(x.dateenvoi);
        return conversationDate >= startDate && conversationDate <= endDate;
    });

    if (filteredByDateRange.length > 0) {
       firstDate = moment(filteredByDateRange[0].dateenvoi);
       lastDate = moment(filteredByDateRange[filteredByDateRange.length - 1].dateenvoi);
    }

    for (var date = firstDate; date <= lastDate; date.add(1, 'h')) {

      var filteredPerHour = filteredByDateRange.filter(function(x) {
      //it's possible to use diff() here
          return moment(x.dateenvoi).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm") == date.format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm");
       });
      for (var i = 0; i < perHourCount; i++) {
         var conversation = filteredPerHour[i];
         if (conversation) {
             result.push(conversation);
         } else {
            result.push({
              dateenvoi: date.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
              Name: 'X',
              City: 'X',
              Country: 'X'
          });
        }
       }
     }
   }
    return result;
   };
});
```